# WordPress / Child Theme - Load parent's options

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a parent theme with a lot of admin options that change the layout, colors and many other things.

When I create a child theme, all the options from the parent theme are not loaded, because, it seems, it create its own options.

I wonder if it is possible to force a child theme to load the options of its parent theme in the "wordpress way" without touching the DB.

Comment: Theme options are supposed be loaded from a parent to a child theme. What exactly is not working?

Comment: The problem is that the child theme loads the default options from the parent theme. Child theme only inherits the main CSS file from parent. But what should I do with options that are loaded from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create automatically the child theme with a plugin like [Child Theme Configurator](http://www.childthemeconfigurator.com/) ?

I have used it with some themes that has given me problems manually, and it has worked. It imports almost everything that comes from the parent.